# JCombobox with Tree type selection items where tree can have check box and individual checkboxes are clickable

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I need to get the selected children nodes. I should be able to select multiple children

```
    JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox();

    jComboBox.setRenderer(new CheckComboRenderer());
    jComboBox.setSize(200, 100);
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    jFrame.add(jComboBox);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node11 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.1");
    node1.add(node11);
    DefaultTreeModel defaultTreeModel1 = new DefaultTreeModel(node1);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node21 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2.1");
    node2.add(node21);
    DefaultTreeModel defaultTreeModel2 = new DefaultTreeModel(node2);

    DefaultComboBoxModel<DefaultTreeModel> defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(defaultTreeModel1);
    defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(defaultTreeModel2);

    jComboBox.setModel(defaultComboBoxModel);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);

class CheckComboRenderer implements ListCellRenderer
{
  JTree tree;

  public CheckComboRenderer()
  {
    tree = new JTree();
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxNodeRenderer());
  }

  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                                Object value,
                                                int index,
                                                boolean isSelected,
                                                boolean cellHasFocus)
  {
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) value;
    tree.setModel(model);
    return tree;
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried initially. It doesn't allow me to select children on tree. There must be some way to do this.

This is my second attempt.       TreeComboBoxUI.this.checkListScrollPane.setViewportView(TreeComboBoxUI.this.getjTree());

Here usually, a component which extends JList() is returned. Here I have tried with jTree. It doesn't show a tree. why?

```
public class MainJJ
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setSize(300, 100);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setSize(200, 50);

    jFrame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    comboBox.setUI(new TreeComboBoxUI());
  }
}

class TreeComboBoxUI<T> extends SyntheticaComboBoxUI
{
  JTree jTree;
  private TreeComboBoxUI<T>.TreeChoicePopup multiChoicePopup;
  private JPanel popupPanel;
  private JScrollPane checkListScrollPane;

  TreeComboBoxUI()
  {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultMutableTreeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultMutableTreeNode2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test1.1");
    defaultMutableTreeNode.add(defaultMutableTreeNode2);
    jTree = new JTree(defaultMutableTreeNode);
  }

  protected TreeComboBoxUI<T>.TreeChoicePopup createPopup()
  {
    if (this.multiChoicePopup == null)
    {
      this.multiChoicePopup = new TreeComboBoxUI.TreeChoicePopup(this.comboBox);
      this.multiChoicePopup.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(this.comboBox);
    }

    return this.multiChoicePopup;
  }

  protected JTree getjTree()
  {
    return jTree;
  }

  private class TreeChoicePopup extends BasicComboPopup
  {
    public TreeChoicePopup(JComboBox comboBox)
    {
      super(comboBox);
      init(comboBox);
    }

    private void init(JComboBox combo)
    {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      this.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(comboBox.isLightWeightPopupEnabled());
      this.add(getPopupPanel());
    }

    private JPanel getPopupPanel()
    {
      if (TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel == null)
      {
        TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel = new JPanel();
        TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel, 1));
        TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel.add(getCheckListScrollPane());
      }

      return TreeComboBoxUI.this.popupPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane getCheckListScrollPane()
    {
      TreeComboBoxUI.this.checkListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(20, 30);
      TreeComboBoxUI.this.checkListScrollPane.setViewportView(TreeComboBoxUI.this.getjTree());
      TreeComboBoxUI.this.checkListScrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);

      return TreeComboBoxUI.this.checkListScrollPane;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. What did you try so far? Any research or implementation details?

Comment: @Thomas I have added what I have tried. But it has problem of not allowing to select children checkboxes

Comment: Why don't you render the tree elements as individual rows in the list model?

Comment: I think you're looking for a [`JTree` with selectable `JCheckBoxes`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm).

Comment: @Thomas it's hierarchical. expected to be appear in hierarchy

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc No. it doesn't have the combobox option

Comment: A hierarchy can still be dispayed with individual rows. Just have a look at how a tree is rendered - this already is just a bunch of rows with elements being indented according to the hierarchy. Maybe what Gilbert suggested would be best: use a button to open a viewport that displays the tree, make nodes expandable or not as you see fit, adjust the look and feel if necessary, and enable tree node selection. This should get you closer to what you want than trying to stuff a tree into a combo box (the need for which I still don't really understand).

Comment: it's kind of mandatory not to have button and showing it as tree